# PHP - Unable to create file

Tags: php, fopen, die

I am trying to create a file on my web server with an option chosen from a web form. The file never gets created and I keep getting the "Can't Open File" message.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["style"])) {
            $boots = $_POST["style"];
    }
    $file = "bootsstyle";
    if(!file_exists($file)) {
            touch($file);
            chmod($file, 0777);
    }
    $openFile = fopen($file, "w+") or die("Can't open file");
    fwrite($openFile, $boots);
    fclose($openFile);
?>
```

I have been scouring the Internet for an hour and am not sure where I am going wrong. I have checked the permissions in the directory and they are 0777.

Comment: Try to check output of php_info, it might be that local file operations are disabled for security reasons?

Comment: Well; does the `file_exists` get called? Does that barf out? If the file exists you might not have access to the file anyway..

Comment: PHP has some "security" options that could be blocking you

Comment: dude your code is working

Comment: Since you use the w+ flag in open, touch is not necessary and chmod seems a bad idea to me. (at least with 777).

Comment: `I have checked the permissions in the directory and they are 0777` try to check the permissions of the file instead.

Comment: I was able to get it resolved by manually creating the file and setting the permissions. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2):

```
$boots = "your data";
$file = "bootsstyle";
if(!file_exists($file)) {
    touch($file);
    chmod($file, 0777);
}
$openFile = fopen($file, "w+") or die("Can't open file");
fwrite($openFile, $boots);
fclose($openFile);
$myfile=fopen($file, "r");
echo fread($myfile,filesize($file));
fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the permissions for the directory in which you are trying to create the file. The directory in which the php script is located must be writable by the user group named ***www-data***. There are two methods to solve this.

### Method 1: Changing permission of directory

You can just change the permission of directory to 777. To do this, open a terminal and navigate to the directory in which your php script resides. Now execute the command 
`sudo chmod 777 ./`

### Method 2: Making www-data as owner of directory

Open a terminal and navigate to the directory containing the php script. Now, execute the command 
`sudo chown www-data ./ && sudo chmod 774 ./`

You can learn more about Linux permissions and the difference between 774 and 777 from 
https://linode.com/docs/tools-reference/linux-users-and-groups/

> Note:
> Opening a file in w+ mode create the file if it does not exist. So you do not have to touch it.
>
> Note:
> The above code is tested on kali linux 2017.3.2 running LAMP server.